Faster way to calculate Jaccard Similarity Scores across large datasets
I am trying to fuzzy-match two different datasets, which are quite large. (One of them has approximately 1 million business names, and the other around 30 thousand).
I want to calculate the similarity score based on Jaccard Similarities on n-grams.
Here is what I have implemented so far, which is a very naive approach that simply loops through each row of the dataset, calculating similarity scores one-by-one.
# Initial match with Jaccard similarity > 0.5
matches = [] 
for idx_a, row_a in data_b.iterrows():
    for idx_b, row_b in df_new.iterrows():
        ngrams_a = ngrams(row_a['name_std'], n=5)
        ngrams_b = ngrams(row_b['name_std'], n=5)
        score = jaccard_similarity(ngrams_a, ngrams_b)
        matches.append({
            'permno_adj': row_a['permno_adj'],
            'firm_name': row_b['name_std'],
            'rec_name': row_a['name_std'],
            'rec_id': row_b['rec_id'],
            'similarity_score': score
        })
matches_df = pd.DataFrame(matches)
matches_df.sort_values(by=['firm_name', 'similarity_score'], ascending=False, inplace=True)

I simply start off the loop by selecting row from dataset1, and then calculating similarity score between that row and the rest of the rows in dataset2, and store the results.
This process, for obvious reasons, takes too much time to run. Based on the current speed - I should expect this to run for a week or two. I am looking whether there could be an option to fasten this up.
I am looking for any hint/feedback. Thanks in advance!
